# I dont find google-play-services_lib version 4.2.34

Tags: android

I wanna find google-play-services_lib library least version 4.2.34.
Because develope chromecast feature.
But i cant find that.

SDK Manager in eclipse, revision is 14..:(

By country ever deployed sequentially on?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fired the SDK Manager and found that even in my sdk the version of Google Play Services in 14. Also, there was no sign of an update in the 'Status' column.

So, I don't know why you want 4.x.x, but the latest version, as of today, is 14

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android/issues/5

That source is google cast recommended source github. Reply that.
Not yet. Thank you.